# Split a String at a certain point

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a users email address if the length is greater than 18 characters.  I want to remove all characters after the 18th character.  Is there a way to split a string at a certain index without having to first turn it into an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s[0,18]` will do it.

```
"Now is"[0,18] #=> "Now is"
"Now is the time for all good people"[0,18] #=> "Now is the time fo"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
> "a very very very looooooooooooong string"[0, 18]
#=> "a very very very l"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use *regex* also for your purpose. This would be a fun, but not to show, that it is a better answer although :-

```
"Now is"[/.{,18}/] # => "Now is"
```

[`String#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) method takes *regex* as an argument

> If a `Regexp` is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the `MatchData` is returned instead.